# Opening all pdf files in a folder using cmd or bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder which have around 20 pdf files inside. Is there any way to open all the pdf in the folder in one shot like using something "* .pdf"?

Comment: which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IFF you are on Microsoft Windows and you have the correct association setup, you could do the following. Of course, there are other things to do like getting to or specifying the directory containing the .pdf files. If you put this into a .bat script, be sure to double the '%' characters on the variable.

```
FOR %f IN ("*.pdf") DO ("%~f")
```